# Use button to execute code and stop when done

Tags: c#, function

I’m quite new with C# so it’s probably not a hard question.
I would like to execute code, let’s call it a function, which starts when I press a button.
When is start this function, I want that it keeps being executed. 
When its finally done I want to stop the function.
How can I do this? Or even better, whats the best way to do this?

If it’s not yet clear what I mean, here is a little example:

Start button is pressed --> Start executing function:

```
Send “Command_1”
If ( “Command_1” has been received) 
{   
    Send “Command_2”
} 

If ( “Command_2” has been received) 
{   
    Close function
}
```

Comment: :please elaborate your question

Comment: When your function has finished executing, it will automatically "stop". You won't need to press another button. However, if you want your function to continue indefinitely in a loop till a button is pressed, then `BackgroundWorker` component is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BackgroundWorker for it. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Background worker to solve your isse

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

while calling `bw.RunWorkerAsync()`; the **bw.DoWork** will automatically executed and after completing the method execution **bw_RunWorkerCompleted** will execute

Answer (score 0):

wat you can do is create a timer object and set the tick event handler to your method on click of the button you just enable the timer and on click of some other button disable the timer as long as the timer is enabled the function (defined by you) keeps running.